# capture Corresponding value from a variable using function

Tags: r

df

```
Group, Sales,flag,Count
Paris,6738,0,15
Paris,5235,1,23
Paris,5907,1,15
Paris,5527,0,28
Paris,6934,1,27
Paris,6757,0,20
Paris,5394,1,31
Paris,5379,0,36
Paris,6266,1,40
Paris,5512,1,39
Paris,6506,1,29
Paris,5006,1,22
Paris,6465,1,17
Paris,6653,0,38
Paris,6719,0,12
New York,5333,1,19
New York,6763,1,37
New York,6468,0,32
New York,6923,0,34
New York,6705,0,16
New York,6542,0,11
New York,6497,0,19
New York,6616,0,27
New York,6788,0,26
New York,5876,1,33
New York,5382,0,40
New York,5688,0,34
New York,6667,1,20
New York,5929,1,28
New York,6096,0,30
```

For each city, I would like to calculate the median sales for consecutive zeros that lie before and after flag “1”, for each city.

Below is code i am using.

```
do.call(rbind,
        by(x, list(x$City, cumsum(c(0,diff(x$flag)!=0))),
           function(a) { a$Sales <- median(a$Sales) ; a[1,,drop=FALSE] ; }))
```

I also want to compute the corresponding value of Count for each median(a$Sales) identified. **For e.g. Count - 27 for 6616 (New York, FLag=0).**

[image]

Not sure how to customize the code, to achieve the desired result.

Moreover, since i am using Median, it will perfectly capture the corresponding value when number of the observations are odd, however for even number of observations it will take the mean of central two terms. Not sure how to do the same in the existing code.

Answer (score 1):

Improving on OP's existing work, you can use `approx` to estimate this count when number of obs is even.

```
ans <- do.call(rbind,
    by(df, paste(df$City, cumsum(c(0, diff(df$Flag)!=0))),
        function(a) { 
            if (nrow(a) > 1) {
                m <- median(a$Sales)
                pc <- approx(a$Sales, a$Count, m)$y
            } else {
                m <- a$Sales[1L]
                pc <- a$Count[1L]
            }
            data.frame(Group=a$Group[1L], Flag=a$Flag[1L], Median=m, PredCount=pc)
        })
)
ans[ans$Flag==0,]
```

data:

```
df <- read.csv(text="Group,Sales,Flag,Count
Paris,6738,0,15
Paris,5235,1,23
Paris,5907,1,15
Paris,5527,0,28
Paris,6934,1,27
Paris,6757,0,20
Paris,5394,1,31
Paris,5379,0,36
Paris,6266,1,40
Paris,5512,1,39
Paris,6506,1,29
Paris,5006,1,22
Paris,6465,1,17
Paris,6653,0,38
Paris,6719,0,12
New York,5333,1,19
New York,6763,1,37
New York,6468,0,32
New York,6923,0,34
New York,6705,0,16
New York,6542,0,11
New York,6497,0,19
New York,6616,0,27
New York,6788,0,26
New York,5876,1,33
New York,5382,0,40
New York,5688,0,34
New York,6667,1,20
New York,5929,1,28
New York,6096,0,30")
```

Comment: I get an error "Error in tapply(seq_len(30L), list(`paste(df$City, cumsum(c(0, diff(df$Flag) != 0)))` = " 0"),  : 
  arguments must have same length"

Comment: @DJV i added the data

Comment: Error in approx(a$Sale, a$Count,m): need at least two non-NA values to interpolate

Comment: You have some NAs in your data. How do you want to handle those?